# Expected value is equal to $\infty$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, matlab

Given the following set:
$$
M=\{2^k | k \in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\}=\{2,4,8,16,...\}
$$

Now we chose randomly some elements. For this we have to define a distribution:
$$
P(m\in M)=m^{-1}
$$

As can be seen this is true:
$$
P(m\in M)>0
$$
and
also:
$$
\sum_{m\in M} P(m)=1
$$

It is possible to calculate the expected value:
$$
E[M]=\sum_{m\in M} m*P(m)=\sum_{m\in M} m*m^-1=\sum_{m\in M}1=\infty
$$

This confuses me a bit. So i implemented a matlab script which choses random numbers from this set with the given distribution:

```
function k = random_k()
    k = 1;
    while rand(1) >= 0.5
        k = k + 1;
    end
end

num = 2^random_k();
disp(sprintf('Chosen number: %d\n', num));
```

The values which i get are not too big. And of course they are much smaller than $\infty$. Obviously always a value less than $\infty$ must be returned. The only special case is that $k$ goes to $\infty$, but this seems to be almost impossible if "real" randomness would be used.

What did i do wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your computations are correct. This is known as the St. Petersburg paradoxon. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox).

Comment: Your question makes no sense as written. First $M$ is defined as a set of positive integers, then later it somehow becomes a random variable (since we are computing an expected value)? Who is $\mathbb P(m)$? Moreover, the expression $\mathbb P(m\in M)$ is shorthand for $\mathbb P(\omega: m(\omega)\in M)$ where $m$ is a random variable and $$\{m\in M\}=\{\omega:m(\omega)\in M\}$$ is an event. How exactly are you defining the expression $\sum_{m\in M}$, then?

Comment: Thanks for the keyword "St. Petersburg paradoxon":) Also thanks for the hint that the notation is wrong. You are right. I just tried to write it down as simple as possible (and hopefully also correct), but my math skills are very limited, so i did it wrong.

Comment: I was also confused by using $M$ as both a set and a random variable, and using an expectation $E[M]$. If you want to keep $M$ as the set of powers of 2, i.e., $M = \{2^1, 2^2, 2^3, ...\}$, you would define the random variable $X$ with mass function $P[X=m]=\frac{1}{m}$ for all $m \in M$.  Then indeed $$E[X] = \sum_{m\in M} mP[X=m]=\sum_{m \in M} \frac{m}{m} = \infty$$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the correct notation:)! It's good to know how it should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did right ! The expectation is indeed $\infty$. Intuitively this is because the probability of getting a really large number (like $2^{1000}$) is decreasing slower than the values themselves are getting larger. So even though it is unlikely to pick a really large number, the value of this large compensate more than its own low probability.

In order to have a finite expectation you would have define probability smaller than $m^{-1}$ to compensate the large numbers !

For example let's take $p(m) = 3/m^2$.

You can check that :
$$
\sum_{m\in M} p(m) = 3\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2^i)^2} = 3\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^i} = 1
$$
Then the expectation is :
$$
\sum_{m\in M} p(m)\cdot m = 3\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^i} \cdot 2^i = 3\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} = 3 < \infty
$$